# Cannot do migration in Visual Studio 2015 using Entity Framework 6.1.3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

**Problem**

> The term 'enable-migrations' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
>
> At line:1 char:18
>   + enable-migrations <<<<
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (enable-migrations:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException .

I work in Visual Studio 2015, with ASP.NET MVC 5 & Entity Framework 6.1.3

Suddenly when I do `enable-migrations`, it's not working, also `update-database` and add migrations are not working.

I work on Windows 7 64 bit.

Answer (score 0):

Check if Entity Framework is added in your project and you are trying to enable migration in the right project. Possibly you have multiple projects in same solution and EF is added in one project and you are trying to enable migration in another project. If EF is not already added try adding it by `Install-Package EntityFramework` in the Package Manager Console.